# Facebook comments no longer displayed on site using WordPress plugin, nor can I edit them with Facebook tools

Tags: facebook, comments

I am using Facebook comments on couple of my blogs at the moment and I just found that somehow magically all the previous comments made on posts are gone and are no longer being displayed.

I'm using wordpress for all of these blogs and [Facebook Comments for WordPress](http://we8u.com/facebook-comments/) to manage all the facebook comments. But somehow they all disappeared all of a sudden.

Another problem which I've been facing lately is that I can't seem to moderate the faceboook comments. When I go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments where there should be a list of all the comments made on my sites (against the Applications that I've created just for the sake of comments), there is nothing there. This has been the thing from the starting, **before the comments vanished on my site, today**

So technically, there are two issues to solve here.

Comment: Please elaborate more about why this is a to programming problem. Your current problem description would seem to indicate that you've used a Wordpress plugin to handle FB comments. If so, then you probably should ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Because it all deals with Facebook Graph API and not entirely a Wordpress only issue

Comment: I still think people here need a lot more information about this problem. For instance, the code to include that plugin, any configuration code (like meta-tags, javascript code, etc.) that authenticate with Facebook, etc. Your problem is basically the same as "My car used to work, now it doesn't. What gives?".

Answer (score 1):

The way we determine who can admin the comments is by looking at the `fb:admins` or `fb:app_id` meta tag in the header of the page where the comments are located. If you've added your user id or your app id, then you should be able to admin your comments. It looks like the instructions for the plugin you've mentioned have a section about adding your own app id.
Take a look at the `moderation tools` section of the comments plugin page on the developer site for detailed instructions on how to set up your page so you can moderate the comments.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: I managed to figure out how to insert the comments (using the same Application as before) on the site again. However, all the comments made prior to that have been lost. This logically shouldn't be happening because the comments should be tied up with the Application. So no matter which method I use (the manual one, or the plugin), comments should show up in any case which, is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to the comment unique identifier.
You can find some help in http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xid+comments

More info here http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8417170/how-to-migrate-comments-from-using-url-property-to-href

Be sure you use the last version of the comments plugin and the right tags.